# Android Access Dynamically Added View

Tags: android, forms

My problem is accessing dynamically added component. If we assign id's of views via xml (such as `android:id="@+id/xyz"`, we can reach this view by `findViewById(R.id.xyz)`. However, I want to assign id dynamically, because I will use a `ListView` or a `TableLayout` and I will be adding rows dynamically from database.

Also, I need to know which checkboxes are checked, therefore according to me I should reach the checkboxes by id. I know setId method, but it gets integer value and for example I want to assign ids for my checkboxes like checkbox1, checkbox2, ... checkbox100. And then I want to control for example in a for loop(from 1 to 100) if checkbox1, ..., checkbox100 are checked.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example I want to assign ids for my checkboxes like checkbox1, checkbox2, ... checkbox100

Call `setId()` on each `CheckBox`, supplying your own number.

Comment: Thank you, but setId only gets integer value. For example, if I use setId(1) for the first checkbox, how can I access this checkbox?

R.id.1 is not accessible?

Comment: @BCK: "For example, if I use setId(1) for the first checkbox, how can I access this checkbox?" -- call `findViewById(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I want to set ID such as checkbox1 programmatically instead of android:id="@+id/checkbox1", how can I do this?

Comment: Ok, very very thank you :) I have also question if you are interested in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583994/android-database-update-on-device