# Android Database Update on Device

Tags: android, database, device

I want to update the database of installed application. First of all, I couldn't the database file path; there is no file called mypackage in /data/data/ . How can I find the database file path?

Secondly, I want to delete the old file and replace it my new database. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you make a program with the packagename of com.example.program, your path will be

```
/data/data.com.example.program/databasefile
```

bur for updating it, put your code in onUpdate and change the version number

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: I have no file such you mentioned. /mnt/sdcard/Android/data contains basic packages such as com.google.android.app.maps and my database file is not here. But I'm sure my application is using database.

Comment: The databases are not stored on the SDcard, they are stored in the root folder at the path I listed above

Comment: It may be silly, but I don't know how can I access root folder.

Comment: unless the phone is rooted, you won't be able to, but if you use Eclipse to program your app there is a way to pull a file from the emulator. You can probably do it with other programming programs but I don't know how to use them, in eclipse, open the DDMS by clicking WINDOW, OPEN PERSPECTIVE, OTHER then click on DDMS. once started, click the FILE EXPLORER tab on the right, then DATA and then DATA again, then your package, then your database file. in the upper right there is a button called "Pull a file from device" and save it to your harddrive.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, thank you for your reply. I will try it as soon as possible.